# SPFolder.MoveTo functionality in JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, folder

In SharePoint 2013 I'm trying to add a script to move a folder from it's current location to a different parent folder while keeping the rest of the file structure the same. I am adding a button to the ECB to do this. Here is my relevant code:

```
var folder;

function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        this.web = clientContext.get_web();
        this.folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder));
        clientContext.load(this.folder);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var path = decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder).replace('Open','Closed');
    this.folder.MoveTo(path, true);
    this.folder.update();
    window.location = path;
}
```

Is there a way to get the same functionality as `SPFolder.MoveTo()` in JavaScript? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSOM [SP.Folder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407837%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not provide `MoveTo` method as SSOM [SPFolder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.aspx) does.
But [SP.File.moveTo(newUrl, flags) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658974%28v=office.14%29.aspx) could be utilized to move folder content (files) from source folder into destination as demonstrated below.

### How to move files via JSOM

```
function moveFiles(folderSrcUrl,folderDescUrl,success,error)
{  
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderSrcUrl);
    context.load(folderSrc,'Files');
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            //move files from source into destination folder 
            var files = folderSrc.get_files();
            var e = files.getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
              var file = e.get_current();
              var fileDescUrl = folderDescUrl + file.get_name(); 
              file.moveTo(fileDescUrl, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
            }
            folderSrc.deleteObject();  //delete source folder
            context.executeQueryAsync(
              function() {
                success();
              }, 
              error);
    }, 
    error);
}
```

Usage

```
//Example. Move files to archive
var srcFolderUrl = '/Shared Documents/Orders/';
var destFolderUrl = '/Shared Documents/Archive/';
moveFiles(srcFolderUrl,destFolderUrl,
   function(){
      console.log('Files are sent to archive');
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But, is there a way to move the all sub directories and files if they are unknown?

Comment: Unfortunately you cant move folders, but you could read source folder structure, then create target folders and move files to them.

Comment: Can I move files to SkyDrive using this code running in current page or in a SharePoint hosted app with tenant permissions?